# Converting %20 into spaces using PHP

Tags: php, url

I'm currently trying to pull the last words from the url after the slash and print them inside a H2 tag.

I'm using this line:

```
<h2>
    <?php 
        echo basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
    ?>
</h2>
```

Currently if after the slash there is multiple words I'm getting %20 in-between the words, how do I go about adapting my code to convert that into a space?

Any Advice or guidance is appreciated.

Cheers :)

Comment: What have you tried?  Any particular functions to convert `%20` to space?  Do you think there might be one?

Comment: use str_replace('%20',' ', basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)))

Comment: try `urldecode()`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `urldecode(string)` to decode a URL into their correct characters. It’s the opposite of `urlencode(string)`.

**NB** Don’t use with `$_GET`, as that is already decoded and could cause issues.

See [urldecode from the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) for more.

Answer (score 3):

Use `urldecode();`  in php

```
$a = basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
$b = urldecode($a);
echo $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Javascript function [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). The following

```
decodeURIComponent('foo%20bar')
```

produces `"foo bar"`.

Or you can use a PHP approach by wrapping your code inside [`rawurldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) function.

> Returns a string in which the sequences with percent (%) signs
>   followed by two hex digits have been replaced with literal characters.

Comment: Thanks Eric, had not thought of using Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work.

```
echo preg_replace("/\s+/","",basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
```

Comment: Boo.  Using regex should be plan Z.

Comment: why?? and how is it posible to come space between url? can you send me the full url that you geting?